# Grep and paginate log file

Tags: linux, logging, sed, grep, tail

I try to disaply a log file in a web interface. File is big, so I should to paginate it. The fastest example I tried is to use linux commands in php:

```
$fp = 'filename.txt';
$tmp = shell_exec("wc -l $fp"); // count lines
$from = 1;
$to = 100;
$text = shell_exec("sed -n '$from,{$to}p' $fp | tail -r");
```

it gives me lines from 1 to 100 in reversed order to show newer first. 
Now I'd like to modify a command to allow search. I planned to use grep command, but my modification does not work:

```
$text = shell_exec("grep 'searchstring' $fp | sed -n '$from,{$to}p' | tail -r");
```

I want to perform grep on while file and then paginate found lines. 
I have poor knowledge of linux commands and pipes, so I have no idea how to modify it to make it work. Can anybody help? And also will be good if you could help to modify `wc -l` command to count only matching lines. Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to accept user input, **beware of shell injections**. I mean, what if `$fp = " -; rm -rf"`?

Answer (score 0):

awk is certainly better in this case (doing all in once)

try

```
$text = shell_exec("grep 'searchstring' $fp | sed -n \"${from},{$to} p\" | tail -r");
```

to allow the shell to substitute $from and $to to their value (simple quote take it litteraly)